# VBA code Userform Equal Operator not working

Tags: excel, vba, userform

This one is confusing me a lot . I don't understand why it's not working when I try to compare the textbox value of a user form with a cell in excel. Here is an example.

Lets assume cell A1=25 on the excel form

So now I have a userform(textbox) named TextBox1

Here is my code
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
   If Me.TextBox1.Value = Cells(1, 1).Value Then
    MsgBox ("Repetition")
   Else
  MsgBox ("No Repetition")
  End If

 End Sub'''
```

Using this code, I am not getting "Repetition" but instead "No Repetiton" which is inccurate

But when I designate a variable ron  to the textbox value as below;

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ron As Long
    ron = TextBox1.Value

   If ron = Cells(1, 1).Value Then
   MsgBox ("Repetition")
   Else
   MsgBox ("No Repetition")
   End If
   End Sub
```

Using this code, I am getting the right answer which returns me "Repetition"

Can someone clarify this to me?

Thnx

Comment: When you break in the debugger and inspect the .Value properties directly, are they the same? If that is a string comparison then whitespace or formatting would be important.

Comment: How do I break in the debugger? I am quite sure I am not missing the whitespace or if there is any formatting issue.

Comment: I think you can right click on the line to break on, and/or press F9 to create a breakpoint. Then you can use the Immediate window (CTRL-G, I think) to inspect variables. (Feel free to google any of these common topics)

Comment: If cell A1 has the value 25, then `Cells(1, 1).Value` gives an `Integer` or maybe `Long` (a numeric value). `Me.TextBox1.Value` returns a `String`. You should use something like `If Val(Me.TextBox1.Value) = Cells(1, 1).Value Then`. When you assign the value of the textbox to a variable of type `Long` then there's an implicit conversion to `Long`

Comment: Thank you. That did solve the problem @ Super Symmetry .